# Is there a closed form solution to a line of best fit given 3 points?

Tags: closed-form

I'm trying to create a program that quickly does a best fit line with 3 points. So i came here to ask if there was a closed form solution to this problem.
Thanks

Comment: How are you defining 'best fit line'?  Standard least squares regression or something else?

Comment: Apologies, standard least squared regression.

Comment: Look up the regression line in google?

Comment: Yes, there is.  Most solutions will have a sum over an arbitrary number of points, but you can just specialize to three.